# How to switch between TextBox and RichTextBox via templates

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox, controltemplate

I want to write a TextBox control which is a RichTextBox when it is out of focus, and when it is focused it becomes a TextBox.

I tried several methods, but none of them are working. The only solution that is almost working, looks like this:

```
<RichTextBox x:Name="headText" Document="{Binding HeadDocument}" GotFocus="headText_GotFocus" LostFocus="headText_LostFocus">
        <Controls:HyperlinkRichTextBox.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="headTemplate">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Head}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Controls:HyperlinkRichTextBox.Resources>
</RichTextBox>
```

and in the code behind:

```
private ControlTemplate oldTemplate;

private void headText_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var controlTemplate = headLineText.FindResource("headTemplate") as ControlTemplate;
    oldTemplate = headText.Template;
    headText.Template = controlTemplate;
    headText.Focus();
}

private void headText_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    headText.Template = oldTemplate;
}
```

The problem is that although the textbox is switching between the two states, I can't write anything into the textbox!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article should get you started : http://weblogs.asp.net/thomaslebrun/archive/2009/03/24/wpf-how-to-develop-and-editable-textblock.aspx

Here is an adaptation, you would need to add the value binding part of the TextBox and RichTextBox :

XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:EditableTextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:EditableTextBlock}">
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_GridContainer">
                            <RichTextBox x:Name="PART_TbDisplayText" Visibility="Visible" />
                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TbEditText" Visibility="Hidden" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="RichTextBox">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Blue" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:EditableTextBlock />
        <Button>Lose focus</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
[TemplatePart(Type = typeof(Grid), Name = EditableTextBlock.GRID_NAME)]
[TemplatePart(Type = typeof(RichTextBox), Name = EditableTextBlock.RICHTEXTBOX_DISPLAYTEXT_NAME)]
[TemplatePart(Type = typeof(TextBox), Name = EditableTextBlock.TEXTBOX_EDITTEXT_NAME)]
public class EditableTextBlock : Control
{
    private const string GRID_NAME = "PART_GridContainer";
    private const string RICHTEXTBOX_DISPLAYTEXT_NAME = "PART_TbDisplayText";
    private const string TEXTBOX_EDITTEXT_NAME = "PART_TbEditText";

    private Grid gridContainer;
    private RichTextBox richTextBox;
    private TextBox textBox;

    static EditableTextBlock()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(EditableTextBlock), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(EditableTextBlock)));
    }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        this.gridContainer = this.Template.FindName(GRID_NAME, this) as Grid;

        if (this.gridContainer != null)
        {
            this.richTextBox = this.gridContainer.Children[0] as RichTextBox;
            this.richTextBox.GotFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(richTextBoxGotFocus);
            this.textBox = this.gridContainer.Children[1] as TextBox;
            this.textBox.LostFocus += this.textBoxLostFocus;
        }
    }

    private void richTextBoxGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.richTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        this.textBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.textBox.Focus();
    }

    private void textBoxLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.richTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        this.textBox.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out! One note: a think a this.textBox.Focus() should be included in the textBoxLostFocus method...

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess but i would say its because you completely change the Template of your rich text box. Remember a ControlTemplate is how your control is made up. A lot of controls allow you to completely modify it, but sometimes contain elements named with "PART_XYZ" these indicates "If you remove me, my parent templated control will not function correctly". My guess now is that your RichtTextBox, which you seem to extend won't find any necessary PART_ controls and goes into an disabled mode, therefore your contained textbox is disabled aswell.

My advice is, use a UserControl, which switches the template. Providing 2 templates one with a textbox one with a richtextbox.